# re: Sharepoint Column Codes

Tags: list, data, merge

Does anyone have a cheat list for column coding is sharepoint. For example, i want to create a column that pulls information from a column i created called employee first name and another column, employee last name.

Result : Column will have employee first name and last name together

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by creating a new calculated column and use this as a formula (I used the column names from your question, so update them if necessary):

```
=[employee first name]&" "&[employee last name]
```

[This page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3) contains more on the formulas that can be used in calculated columns.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works when I am in the list and do it by using a column Calculated field. I tried doing this from my site content type list and since the Last Name is the (item), it does not allow me to use it as a lookup. Is that normal? Either, the work around I found with your code, works perfect. Thanks for responding so quick! I really appreciate you help.